# Sorting an array of length $n$ in $O(m+n)$ time

Tags: time-complexity, sorting, arrays, radix-sort

I need to find a method to sort an array in $O(m+n)$ time complexity.
I understand it should be a variation on Radix sort, however I am not familiar with it or its implementation...

> *Input*: an array $A$ of length $n$, containing values from $-m$ to $m$
>
> *Output*: a sorted array $A$

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use counting sort. In $O(n)$, count the number of elements of each value, and then in $O(m+n)$ go over the histogram and translate it to the sorted array.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail, or provide any links or pseudocode on how to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: @Lola1984 If you look up counting sort, you shouldn't need any more information.

Comment: This is probably already too much information.

Comment: @Lola1984 counting sort is synomynous with histogram